# Parent entity sorted by votes difference

Tags: sql, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have three models that look like this (I just left the stuff important for the question):

```
class Symbol < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :mnemonic
end

class Mnemonic < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :symbol
  has_many :mnemonic_votes
end

class MnemonicVote < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :mnemonic
  attr_accessible :vote_up
end
```

:vote_up is of boolean type which if true means someone upvoted the mnemonic, and if false means someone downvoted it.

I would like to get top three mnemonics by vote difference. Let's say there are 5 mnemonic records in the database with the following number of up/down votes (MnemonicVote records with true/false as :vote_up field):

```
mnemonic      up   down  total
mnemonic1      3     2     1
mnemonic2     17     3    14
mnemonic3      2     5    -3
mnemonic4     11     7     4
mnemonic5      5     5     0
```

I would like to get the following three mnemonics (with counts) by descending order:

```
mnemonic2  14
mnemonic4   4
mnemonic1   1
```

I wrote this actual code which gives me the result I want, but I am aware it sucks and I don't like how I did it because the data gets grouped and sorted *after* all the MnemonicVote records associated with a certaing Mnemonic record are fetched from the DB:

```
@mnemonics = Mnemonic.where(symbol_id: self.id)   # here I fetch all Mnemonics associated with Symbol table
@mnemonics.sort_by { |mnemonic| mnemonic.votes_total }.reverse!
return @mnemonics.take(3)
```

where mnemonic.votes_total is a calculated attribute on Mnemonic object. I would like to get the same result by using a single AR (or even SQL) query. How can this be accomplished? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both answers were on the right track, except the IF clause that did not work with PostgreSQL (I would get *function if(boolean, integer, integer) does not exist*). Here is my final solution in case someone needs it:

```
Mnemonic.
  select("mnemonics.*, SUM(CASE WHEN mnemonic_votes.vote_up THEN 1 ELSE -1 END) AS votes_total").
  joins(:mnemonic_votes).
  where(symbol_id: self.id).
  group("mnemonics.id").
  order("votes_total DESC").
  limit(3)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you want:

```
Mnemonic.
  joins(:mnemonic_votes).
  select("mnemonics.*, SUM(IF(mnemonic_votes.upvote, 1, -1)) AS vote").
  group("mnemonics.id").
  order("vote DESC").
  map { |m| [m.symbol, m.vote.to_i] }
```

Comment: Thank you, got me on the right track, although IF clause didn't work like that because of PostgreSQL.